# How to include different catalogs in a query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose I have different documents in different collections:

On **cars**:

```
{ "_id": 32534534, "color": "red", ... }
```

On **houses**:

```
{ "_id": 93867, "city": "Xanadu", ... }
```

How can I retrieve the corresponding document to the documents below, in **people**:

```
{ "name": "Alonso", "owns": [32534534], ... }
{ "name": "Kublai Khan", "owns": [93867], ... }
```

---

Can I use something like the code below?
(Note that I'm not specifying a catalog)

```
db.find({'_id': 93867})
```

If not, what would you suggest to achieve this efect?

---

I have just found this related question: [MongoDB: cross-collection queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745566/mongodb-cross-collection-queries)

Comment: in NoSQL it's preferable to have embedded documents over link to other collections. Let 'cars' and 'houses' be embedded in 'people' collection

Comment: @Arseny: What about the cases where (a) 'cars' and 'houses' can be owned by more then one person; and (b) 'cars' and 'houses' will usually (also) be queried alone, without a person and disregarding any relationship with its owner? Should I have a representation of those documents both by themselves and also embedded in documents in 'people' collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [DBrefs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef) you can store links to documents outside your collection or even in another mongodb database.  You will have to fetch the references in separate queries, different drivers handle this differently, for example with the python driver you can [auto dereference](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/cd47b2475c5fe567e98696e6bc5af3c402891d12/examples/auto_reference.py).

An example of yours in the js shell might look like:

```
> red_car = {"color": "red", "model": "Ford Perfect"}
{"color": "red", "model": "Ford Perfect"}
> db.cars.save(red_car)
> red_car
{
    "color" : "red",
    "model" : "Ford Perfect",
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f041d96874e6f24e704f887")
}
> // Save as DBRef
> alonso = {"name": "Alonso", "owns": [new DBRef('cars', red_car._id)]}
{
    "name" : "Alonso",
    "owns" : [
        {
            "$ref" : "cars",
            "$id" : ObjectId("4f041d96874e6f24e704f887")
        }
    ]
}
> db.people.save(alonso)
```

As you can see DBRefs are a formal spec for referencing objects, that always contain the `ObjectId` but also can contain information on the database and the collection.  In the above example you can see it stores the collection `cars` in the `$ref` field.  Searching is trivial as you just do a query on the dbref:

```
> dbref = new DBRef('cars', red_car._id)
> red_car_owner = db.people.find({"owns": {$in: [dbref]}})[0]
> red_car_owner
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f0448e3a1c5cd097fc36a65"),
    "name" : "Alonso",
    "owns" : [
        {
            "$ref" : "cars",
            "$id" : ObjectId("4f0448d1a1c5cd097fc36a64")
        }
    ]
}
```

Dereferencing can be done via the `fetch()` command in the shell:

```
> red_car_owner.owns[0].fetch()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f0448d1a1c5cd097fc36a64"),
    "color" : "red",
    "model" : "Ford Perfect"
}
```

However depending on your use case you may want to optimise this and write some code that iterates over the `owns` array and does as few `find()` queries as possible...

Comment: Thanks, Ross. Using DBrefs is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way of achieving querying from multiple collections at once. I may suggest storing them inside the same collection like below with a `type` field.

```
{ "_id": 32534534, "type": "car", "color": "red", ... }
{ "_id": 93867, "type": "house", "city": "Xanadu", ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your people document to have a type to be added

```
{ "name": "Alonso", "owns": {ids:[32534534],type:'car'} ... }
{ "name": "Kublai Khan", "owns":{ids:[93867],type:'house'} ... }
```

so now you can find the people who owns the red color car by

```
db.people.find({type:car,ids:32534534})
```

and houses by

```
db.people.find({type:house,ids:93867})
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to do the opposite. I have the person and I want to find the document with the id specified in 'owns'.