# Group-based Cross-Collection query in Mongodb (inc. Having clause)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following SQL Query that needs to be translated to Mongodb and I just cant find a good way of doing it (which doesnt entail loading documents from two collections and perform a query programmatically)

> Select user_id, count(1) as cnt From user_data where data_type = 3 and
>   user_id not in (select user_id from blocked_users) group by user_id
>   having cnt > 1

It would be great if anyone could give me a hand.

I am using MongoDB 2.2.

Comment: As mentioned here this is now possible since Mongodb 3.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745566/mongodb-cross-collection-queries/44141862#44141862

Answer (score 1):

There are no joins in mongo so what you have to do is design a schema from a document-oriented point of view; that is, when migrating from a relational schema don't bring it over verbatim.

In this particular case the best thing would be to have a blocked: field in the users collection i think.